# Command window cannot locate files says "cannot find the path specified"

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-prompt

I'm literally in Chapter 1 of Python Crash Course, I'm trying to make sure the command terminal can locate my hello_world.py file.

The command reads `C:\Users\adamk>`.
I type `cd Desktop` and it says `cannot find the path specified`.

I can't make it find any file, please can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: So your `hello_world.py` is on the Desktop? What do you have in the output if you enter `dir` in your current working directory?

Comment: hello_world.py is in a folder on my desktop, but I can't find the folder by the cd command either. same error message.

Comment: Volume in drive C is Acer
 Volume Serial Number is ***F-E9C3

 Directory of C:\Users\adamk

07/18/2019  08:27 PM    <DIR>          .
07/18/2019  08:27 PM    <DIR>          ..
07/18/2019  08:27 PM    <DIR>          .Origin
07/18/2019  08:27 PM    <DIR>          .QtWebEngineProcess
11/13/2019  06:07 PM    <DIR>          3D Objects
11/13/2019  06:07 PM    <DIR>          Contacts
07/18/2019  06:05 PM    <DIR>          Documents

Comment: So it doesn't appear that your Desktop folder is where it normally lives. Usually Desktop should be in `C:\Users\<user>\Desktop`, but it doesn't appear to be the case. Open your C: drive in File Explorer and in the search bar type Desktop and see where it actually exists.

Comment: There were a lot of results when I performed that search, but the most relevant looked to be a Desktop folder in C:\Users\Default would this make sense?

Comment: No, that's a default Desktop for new users. It should be empty. Nothing in the search came up with your user name in the path?

Comment: there are thousands of results so it might be there but I don't know how to narrow it down

Answer (score 0):

This is odd - same commands worked OK on my computer. Try posting output of `dir` command here

To avoid the issue I suggest you to create a separate folder for python projects, like `c:\python` and store your code files there.

Comment: I do have them in a file called python_work, but the same error message occurs when I search for the file. 

C:\Users\adamk>dir
 Volume in drive C is Acer
 Volume Serial Number is ***F-E***

 Directory of C:\Users\adamk

07/18/2019  08:27 PM    <DIR>          .
07/18/2019  08:27 PM    <DIR>          ..
07/18/2019  08:27 PM    <DIR>          .Origin
07/18/2019  08:27 PM    <DIR>          .QtWebEngineProcess
11/13/2019  06:07 PM    <DIR>          3D Objects
11/13/2019  06:07 PM    <DIR>          Contacts
07/18/2019  06:05 PM    <DIR>          Documents....

Comment: I see that there is no `Desktop` folder in our dir output between `Contacts` and `Documents`. You may have a missing folder issue described and solved at these links (and a few more if searched). Hope that these solutions help you too.
[link one](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/desktop-folder-missing-on-windows-10/7387ea95-4e01-4271-aebf-b7743f0deab0)

[link two](https://www.tenforums.com/general-support/117756-desktop-missing.html)